# Log4j in class not work in jsp page

Tags: log4j

log4j.properties

```
log4j.rootLogger=ON, A1
log4j.logger.org.apache.jsp=DEBUG
log4j.appender.A1=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.A1.File=test.log
log4j.appender.A1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.A1.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}] - %m%n
```

test.java

```
package ch15;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class test
{
    static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(test.class);
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        makeLog();
    }

    public static String makeLog()
    {
        logger.debug("test");
        return "YES";
    }
}
```

When I compile this java file and execute, Log File created Normally.

```
[2013-05-10 16:53:24] - test
```

But when I intend to use this class file in JSP like below, there's no Log at all.

```
<jsp:useBean id="t" class="ch15.test" />
<%=t.makeLog()%>
```

I think JSP call test class successfully because browser displays "YES".

But no log written...

Can you help me? 
I'm in trouble for a week...:(

Comment: Where is the log4j.properties file ? It might need to be deployed along with your webapp to picked up ? Possibly log4j isn't initializing ? Try searching your App Server log - any errors to this effect ? (On Tomcat, check 'catalina.out' for instance).